# Return multiple rows per group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

Is it possible to return multiple rows per group in a grouped command in `data.table`? In `dplyr`, this is done with `reframe`:

```r
y <- c("a", "b", "d", "f")
df <- tibble(
  g = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  x = c("e", "a", "b", "e", "f", "c", "a")
)

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  reframe(x = setdiff(x, y), .by = g)
# g x    
# 1 e    
# 2 e    
# 2 c
```

In `data.table`, this returns an error:

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(df)
dt[, x := setdiff(x, y), g]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(x, intersect(x, y)), g) :
> Supplied 2 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 3 in column 'x'.
> The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the
> LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep()
> explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Anyway to get a `data.table` equivalent of `reframe`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap in `.(...)` and use `=` in place of `:=` (because it's within `.(..)`).

```r
as.data.table(df)[, .(x = setdiff(x, y)), by = g]
#        g      x
#    <num> <char>
# 1:     1      e
# 2:     2      e
# 3:     2      c
```

Note that under the hood, `.(.)` is really just `list(.)`, so we could also use anything that returns `list`-like objects, including:

```r
as.data.table(df)[, list(x = setdiff(x, y)), by = g]
as.data.table(df)[, data.table(x = setdiff(x, y)), by = g]
as.data.table(df)[, data.frame(x = setdiff(x, y)), by = g]
```